Documented apidog api visualiser produces error
visualiser.set method as defined in the docs and it is returning an error.
This is the function I am using
// Encapsulate the API response data into the required structure
var resp = {
    response: pm.response.json()
}

// HTML template string
var template = `<html><img src="{{response.data}}" /></html>`;

// Set visualizer data by passing the template and the parsing object.
pm.visualizer.set(template, resp);

As defined in the docs here apidog docs visualing responses
And it returns this error.
PostProcessor Script Error: Unexpected token '<' at 1:1 <!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="icon" hr ^

Are the docs incorrect or something else I need to do?
